# I can't maintain state of a base class amongst subclasses

Tags: c++, design-patterns, frameworks, directx, game-engine

#### Summary

My goal is to write a rendering engine using `DirectX 11`. I plan to write it in an OOP fashion.
The plan is to write separate classes. Specifically one class for `shader` where I can load, compile, bind and set it for usage. Second class for creating `vertex buffer`, where I can load vertices, bind buffers and set it for rendering.

#### My Attempts

I wrote one base class `A` for initializing DirectX and maintain 2 objects, `m_device` and `m_device_context`. Then as I wrote `2` subclasses `B` and `C`.

At class `B` I create and bind vertex buffers and At `C` I compile and bind vertex shaders.
Both `B` and `C` uses `m_device` object to create objects and `m_device_context` to bind/set them.

In subclass `B`, I use subclass `C` to compile and bind `shaders`.
Using subclass `B` I initialize Base class. but at `C` subclass I get memory `Access violation` on `m_device`. this is probably because I have to reinitialize base class but I can't have different instances of `DirectX` objects.

#### Question

I have read that global variable or objects are not recommended but How do I solve this problem, How do I maintain global objects that I will need thought the project?

(My question is specifically about C++ implementation, not games)

I do not have access to the project but I made a quick UML diagram, I hope this will help clarifies a bit
[image]

Comment: I'm not clear on your class relationships, but I think inheritance (if that's what you're using) probably isn't the right tool here. Maybe dependency injection would be more applicable. If you need more help, maybe you could explain which DirectX objects can only have one instance (for those of us who haven't used DirectX in a while), and/or what your exact class relationships are and where the issue is occurring. If you could clear out everything unnecessary and post a short example, that also might help.

Comment: @scg I made a quick uml diagram, I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: If the connections in your diagram indicate inheritance, then I don't think that's what you want. As I mentioned before, dependency injection seems more reasonable. Instead of using inheritance, pass an instance of the class that handles the device and context as an argument to the constructors of your other classes. Be sure to use shared ownership of some sort (e.g. std::shared_ptr) rather than passing by value. There are other details to consider of course, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: It’s impossible to fully hide the use (read: taint) of global variables underlying an interface; it’s quite possible that the best approach here involves a global of your own to represent the state of the lower-level library that you don’t want to expose as-is to your clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance is built upon a `is-a` relationship. What most people get wrong is that it's not a in perspective of the object itself, but upon the *functionality* that the object brings with it.

In your case, the functionality of the D3D class is to initialize and allocate the 3D engine context. Right?

The Demo and Shader classes do not extend that behavior, which means that there are no `is-a` relationship.

So in your case, those classes requires the D3D class to be able to function. Another solution might be do not use the D3D class at all in Demo or Shader. It depends on if the D3D class provides any other functionality (methods) that the Demo or Shader classes use.

You should also be really careful with exposing fields in your classes since it can become a real headache when your application grows. Try instead to expose functionality through methods.